# Applet, JNLP. Force update jar files

Tags: java, caching, applet, jnlp

How I can force updating of my `jar` files when client open applet application? Jar files always cached in client machine. And I always need to clear cache using Java Control Panel.

Comment: How about deleting cache folder after execution of your app? It should be somewhere in user's `Application Data/Sun` folder.

Comment: @PLB I think there exist some more legant solution..I know that it can be achieved by confugiring JNLP file

Comment: @MyTitle Yes, right. I've written it because you can use one if you are unable to find solution.

Comment: @Dan you are not correct. It can be used with applet as well. And my question not about it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Web Start - How to clear cache (or update the app from user's perspective)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828643/java-web-start-how-to-clear-cache-or-update-the-app-from-users-perspective)

Answer (score 1):

> I always need to clear cache using Java Control Panel.

This is probably because the JWS client does not recognize the Jars as being new.  One source of such confusion lies in the difference in time-zone between the developers machine and that of the server.  In that case, the Jars will typically update within the next 24 hours.

For the purposes of testing, do it outside a browser.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that old versions of the files are present after redeploying new versions, then consider having a form of timestamps or build numbers in your jar file names.

This will require you to update your JNLP file for every deployment, but your cache problems should go away.  It did for us.

Answer (score 0):

Version your jars in your applet tag with each build / deploy.  This will force a reload.

`ARCHIVE="foo-1.0.16.jar" > ARCHIVE="foo-1.0.17.jar"`