# JNLP update ask user only once, then forces the update

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I want to use Java Webstart to keep my application up-to-date. I chose the option

```
<update check="always" policy="prompt-update"/>
```

When a new version of my jar is available, this works fine the first time. I will be asked if I want the new version. If I say yes, the new version is taken, if I say no, the old version is kept. 
However, if I choose to keep the old version, the next time I call the jnlp file, I won't be asked anymore and the new version will always be taken.

Is there any way to fix this problem, such that the user can decline each time to use the new version and to keep the old one?

I tried also

```
<update check="always" policy="prompt-run"/>
```

and it had the same behavior, i.e. the first time, I could decline and my application would not run, and the second time the new version would always be taken.

I use jnlp 6.0+.

In advance, thank you for your help

Comment: Be sure to validate the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://www.pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: I asked the question on the oracle jnlp forum (https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10550253&#10550253) A change request was filed.

Comment: Excellent.  Update this thread as you know more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Applet, JNLP. Force update jar files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053733/applet-jnlp-force-update-jar-files)