# JNLP showing old version of applet

Tags: java, caching, applet, jnlp

I have an applet on a webpage being deployed with JNLP. My problem is that it is loading the cached applet instead of the newly uploaded one.

I have tried:

- [putting `<update check="always" policy="always">` in my JNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828643/java-web-start-how-to-clear-cache-or-update-the-app-from-users-perspective)
- renaming the `.jar` file and changing the JNLP to reflect that
- force refreshing the webpage (I updated the `.html`, so I know that the force refresh worked)
- all of the above

Nothing worked. How can I force JNLP to clear the cache/load the new applet? (I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828643/java-web-start-how-to-clear-cache-or-update-the-app-from-users-perspective) question, but the solution didn't work.)

Comment: Double-check that the timestamps of the server files are actually newer.  I've observed some remote copy tools copying the timestamp after copying the file contents.

Comment: @VGR They were new. I just had to rename the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I had to rename the `.jar` file (and update it in the JNLP) **and** rename the `.jnlp` file (and update it in the HTML).